# Prevent the horizontal expansion of text when being typed.Text can expand vertically

Tags: jquery, html

I have certain piece of code which enables me to type in textarea. I am increasing width of textarea on keypress and i am giving width a limit after which it should stop increasing. What i want is on width limit reach stop typing and when user press enter key start typing again.

Heres Sample code :

```
var maindivwidth = $('.maindiv').width();           
var vWidth = 0;
var hIncr = 2;   
var tWidth = $('textarea')[0].value.length;
var iheight = $(dividfortextbox).css('font-size').replace('px','');

$(dividfortextbox).keypress(function(e) {

if ((e.keyCode || e.which) == 13) {

$(this).parent(dividfortext).css('height', (hIncr * iheight) + 'px');
  vWidth = 0;
  hIncr++;
}
else 
{       
    vWidth = (vWidth+1);

 if (tWidth < maindivwidth-aminus && vWidth*9 > tWidth){
 tWidth = vWidth*9;
 $(this).parent(dividfortext).css('width', (tWidth) + 'px');

 }
 else{
    ??????????????????????????
 } 

 }
 });
```

Comment: What do you mean by "on width limit reach stop typing", do you mean the textarea should stop growing, hence expanding horizontally?
If so, this might be useful for you: http://stackoverflow.com/a/10842271/1262619 just change the expansion from vertical to horizontal and use the same method as in the example for setting a maximum expansion width of the textarea

Comment: Hi thanks for the reply. I have a textarea inside div. And i am increasing div width with keypress. So when the div width reaches the max limit typing should stop and on enter press typing should start.

Comment: Actually the given answer should not have been accepted. It is not exactly what you wanted but an extreme modification of it.Also, what has been achieved in this answer could have been done via simple css.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I got you right, this may be what you're looking for: [Auto grow text area (jsFiddle)](http://jsfiddle.net/8S6ZU/)

No need for the user to press enter here to continue writing, the textarea automatically expands vertically. Depending on the nature of your project, this - although far from perfect! - might very well do the job. Please note that this method requires jQuery, although obviously it can be done without it.

**HTML**

```
<div id="textareaContainer">
   <textarea id="expandTextArea"></textarea>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#expandTextArea {
padding:8px 1%;
height:20px;
width:160px;
font-size:16px;
color:#242424;
border:1px solid #333;

/*important for getting the smooth expansion effect*/
-webkit-transition: height 0.6s;
-webkit-transition-timing-function: height 0.6s; 
-webkit-transition: width 0.6s;
-webkit-transition-timing-function: width 0.6s;

overflow:hidden;
}
```

**Jquery**

```
$('textarea#expandTextArea').live('keydown', function() {

//insert your values here
var expandTextareaAfter = 20; //characters, grow horizontally
var breakRowAfter = 50; // characters, grow vertically
var fontSize = 16; //textarea fontsize in px

var ta = $("#expandTextArea");
var nrOfLetters = ta.val().length;
var newWidth = (nrOfLetters*9);

//check if textarea is full and expand the textarea horizontally/vertically
if ((nrOfLetters >= expandTextareaAfter) && (nrOfLetters <= breakRowAfter)) {
    ta.css("width", newWidth+"px");
} else if (nrOfLetters > expandTextareaAfter) {
    ta.css("height", ((fontSize+1) * (Math.round(nrOfLetters/breakRowAfter))) + "px");
}
});​
```